# suppress the output to screen in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

Hi
i have written a small script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for i in *.DAT
do
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$3~/^353/{$3="353861958962"}{print}' $i >> $i_changed
awk '$3~/^353/' $i_changed >> $i_353
rm -rf $i_changed
done

exit
```

i tested it and its wrking fine.
But it is giving the output to screen i dont need the output to screen.
i simply need the final file that is made `$i_353`

how is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the body of the script in braces and redirect to /dev/null:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

{
for i in *.DAT
do
    awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$3~/^353/{$3="353861958962"}{print}' $i >> $i_changed
    awk '$3~/^353/' $i_changed >> $i_353
    rm -rf $i_changed
done
} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This sends errors to the bit-bucket too.  That may not be such a good idea; if you don't want that, remove the `2>&1` redirection.

Also: **beware** - you probably need to use `${i}_changed` and `${i}_353`.  This is why the output is not going to the files...your variables `${i_changed}` and `${i_353}` are not initialized, and hence the redirections don't name a file.