# Replace sqoop process output

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Wondering if there is any way to somehow hide sqoop process output in Unix shell?

For example instead of that output put some text like "sqoop processing"

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

Comment: Not exactly, it does not solve my problem, still getting sqoop output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [suppress the output to screen in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960567/suppress-the-output-to-screen-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with this for pig scripts (which also tend to give a lot of output, and run for a long time) is as follows:

Rather than running

```
pig mypath/myscript.pig
```

I will run

```
nohup pig mypath/myscript.pig &
```

In your case that would mean something like

```
nohup oozie -job something &
```

This has the additional benefit that it will not stop your query if your SSH connection times out. If you do not use SSH at the moment, this may be an additional required step.